# SQL Date Format from 1YYMMDD to normal

Tags: sql, date, format, db2

I'm using SQL for IBM System i Access for Windows Version 6 Release 1 to extract data from AS400 the green screen. I think that will be DB2?

The date data is formatted 1yymmdd for example, for October 15, 2016 the date will be 1161015. I want the date data to be converted for that column from 1yymmdd format to MM/DD/YYYY and be recognized as a date not a number.

Part of the problem is if I want to check the date difference between two entries, it recognizes it as a number (e.g. 1171015- 1161016 = 10,000) but I want it to be 365 days.

What would be a good conversion method to work with this date format (1yymmdd) to be (MM/DD/YYYY) ?

Example of the code that I am using :

```
sSQL = SELECT A.DATE, curdate() 
            FROM TABLE1 A 
            LIMIT 10
```

The output is as below

```
1141220 8/16/2017
1130308 8/16/2017
1141220 8/16/2017
1141220 8/16/2017
1140822 8/16/2017
1140822 8/16/2017
1141206 8/16/2017
1141220 8/16/2017
1140913 8/16/2017
1141206 8/16/2017
```

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: Functions to convert to and from dates are highly specific to specific RDMS's (Oracle, SQL Server, MySQL, PostgreSQL, ...). Please tag your question with the RDBMS you are using. One thing I suspect is that it is better to capture the data in string format, and do not "copy" the leading `1`.

Comment: I'm not sure what that means, but I'm using sql for ibm iseries

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to figure out how to correctly code that (E.G. A.DATE = 1161015 )

```
SELECT DATE( TIMESTAMP( (A.DATE + 19000000) CONCAT'000000') ) 
FROM TABLE1 A
```

ANSWER:

```
10/15/2016
```

And if you want to find the difference in days (E.G. A.DATE1 = 1161015 , A.DATE2 = 1161215):

```
SELECT  ( DAYS( DATE(TIMESTAMP((A.DATE2 + 19000000) CONCAT'000000'))) - DAYS(DATE(STANMP((A.DATE1+ 19000000) CONCAT'000000'))) )
FROM TABLE1 A
```

ANSWER:

```
58
```

Thanks y'all for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `DATENAME` function to get the name of the month. To get the day and year, just use the `CAST`

`SELECT DATENAME(MM, GETDATE()) AS [DD Month]  + ' ' + CAST(DAY(GETDATE()) AS VARCHAR(2)) + ' ' + CAST(YEAR(GETDATE()) AS VARCHAR(4)) AS [DD Month YYYY]`

You can also view other formats available from the [SQL-SERVER-helper](http://www.sql-server-helper.com/tips/date-formats.aspx) page